# Evaluation of linear system conditioning

Tags: systems-of-equations, condition-number

I am working in Matlab trying to solve a wider problem, that led to 2 linear systems
\begin{equation}
A_1 x = b_1^0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A_2 x = b_2^0
\end{equation}
The matrices and vectors have specific numerical values which I am not giving here since they're very large, with dimensions $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb{R}^{373\times41}, b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{R}^{373}$. The systems have solutions $x_1^0,x_2^0$. Now the right-hand side (RHS) vectors are perturbed to yield $b_1,b_2$ where
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|b_1-b_1^0\|_2}{\|b_1^0\|_2}=0.0781,\quad \frac{\|b_2-b_2^0\|_2}{\|b_2^0\|_2}=0.0032.
\end{equation}
When solving the system for these perturbed vectors I get the solutions $x_1,x_2$ that satisfy
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|x_1-x_1^0\|_2}{\|x_1^0\|_2}=0.0408,\quad \frac{\|x_2-x_2^0\|_2}{\|x_2^0\|_2}=0.0075.
\end{equation}

Visually you can notice the conditioning of system 2 is slightly worse than 1. However, when computing the condition numbers of the matrices via the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse I get
\begin{equation}
\|A_1\|_2\cdot\|A_1^+\|_2=2.34,\quad \|A_2\|_2\cdot\|A_2^+\|_2=155.4.
\end{equation}

So it looks as if system 2 is around 50 times worse conditioned than 1. I know the condition number is just a bound, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|x-x^0\|_2}{\|x^0\|_2}\leq\|A\|_2\cdot\|A^+\|_2\frac{\|b-b^0\|_2}{\|x^0\|_2}
\end{equation}
but in my case this is an extremely loose bound. I want to get a much tighter bound for the terms above than given by the conditioning, that may be able to help me predict how the solution error changes with the errors in vectors b. Any  help or hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: A detail: I see you use the Moore-Penrose inverse for computing the condition number, but you could use directly the "cond" operator of Matlab.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I used both and it gives the same result.

Comment: Something puzzles me : Let us consider for example the first system which has 373 lines and 41 unknowns : when you say $x_1^0$ is "the" solution of the system, you surely mean a least square solution (your use of the pseudo-inverse attests it !) because it is impossible that such a system has a "true" solution. In this case (least square solution) you must reason on system 
$A_1^TA_1 x = A_1^Tb_1^0$. I think that it is the source of the discrepancy you observe : the condition number for example should be taken on matrix $A_1^TA_1$...

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wasn't able to reply. Yes, I am strictly talking about least squares solutions. When I replace $A_i \rightarrow A_i^T A_i$, $b_i^0 \rightarrow A_i^T b_i^0$ and $b_i \rightarrow A_i^T b_i, i=1,2$ I get the following numbers, in the same order as the numbers in the original posting: 
$$0.0319, 1.7238^{-4}, 0.0408, 0.0075, 5.4924, 2.4151^{4}$$

Comment: As expected, the solutions are the same so the corresponding errors are the same. But it seems like the other effects are "amplified": it seems that the conditioning of the second is 4000+ times worse than the first, while in reality it's around 40 times worse. Basically the bound in the last equation in the original posting is a lot looser. What we see is not a discrepancy per se, as the bound is satisfied. It is just a very loose bound that doesn't give me any control over the true conditioning of the systems.

Comment: Another direction : You have abnormally "tall" matrices $A_k$. Have you considered truncating them for example based on the consideration of a threshold on their singular values ? And see if you have almost the same solutions, and if the problem persist on these truncated "versions" ?

Comment: The matrices would only have 41 singular values, corresponding to their smaller dimension, I don't see what to use thresholding for, that would give less than 41 equations. What do we expect to see via these transformations? A case where cond gives you a very tight bound in the last inequality? Is generally cond supposed to give a tight bound in the first place?

Comment: I made an error by saying it depends on the singular values. But it is sure that computing the different "dot-products" of the matrix lines by "solution" $x_0$, you can eliminate those which are relatively far from being zero and eliminate them.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a thought and try to see what comes up. Essentially you're suggesting problems could be solved by working on full-rank matrices right? I wonder if this has any connection with conditioning.

Comment: Not necessarily full rank matrices but matrices where you have eliminated the biggest outliers. A first test is whether these "reduced" matrices have a better conditionning that the initial ones...

Comment: What do you mean by conditioning? The bound, or the actual division of the solution error to the error in the right hand side coefficients?

Comment: I mean the bound. Sorry, I am not an expert in numerical analysis, although I have worked a lot with Matlab, in particular in tomography with overdetermined systems looking a little like yours.

Comment: I am not either, that's why I am still learning about conditioning. I will try your suggestions and report in here if I find any solution.

Comment: Would you please suggest what's the quickest way to reduce the system to a 41x41 system? Is it using svd or qr? Svd would give me 41 values to threshold, but I actually want to threshold the equations not the unknowns. I am basically looking for a system $\bar{A}_1 x=b_1^0$ with $\bar{A}_1\in\mathbb{R}^{41\times41}$ that has a solution $\bar{x}_1\approx x_1^0$. Thanks!

Comment: I remember you suggested computing the matrix lines dot product with the solution, but that's not expected to be 0 but the corresponding element in the RHS vector b right?

Comment: I just posted an answer to your previous comment.

Comment: Thanks I'm reading it!

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment).

What seems me the most rational approach.

Let us consider a system $Ax=b$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{373 \times 41}$, $b$ a column vector with entries $b_k$ and $\overline{x}$ the least square solution, its entries being denoted $\overline{x}_k.$

Let $(R_k)^T$ ($k=1 \cdots 373$) be the rows (which are line vectors) of matrix $A$.

**Caveat :** are these rows more or less normalized (ideally their norms should be all the same) ? If not, it may be a source of problems ; indeed, the more "heavy" the entries of a line are (wrt to others), the more the degree of "attraction" of this line. This should be avoided.

Assuming this normalization done (prior to the determination of lest square solution $\overline{x}$) :

Let $D_k$ be the discrepancy between LHS and RHS at the level of the $k$th row :

$$D_k=\underbrace{(R_k)^T \overline{x}}_{\in \mathbb{R}}-x_k$$

Sort the absolute values of the $|D_k|$s by increasing value and keep track of their resp. index ; keep the first $41$ "winning" equations (i.e., with smallest discrepancies) for building a square system $\tilde{A}x=\tilde{b}$ whose solution $\tilde{x}$ shouldn't be far from the initial least squares solution $\overline{x}$.

Comment: Thank you, that's the general idea I thought of but wasn't sure.

Comment: An important point you made is with the normalisation of the lines. Indeed the lines in the system with a high condition number are heavily not normalised. In fact, they originate from a well- conditioned system whose matrix lines are cumulatively summed (the nth line of $A_2$ results from adding together the first n lines of the well- conditioned system. I can give all details if it's unclear. The reason I do this summation is because it yields much smaller errors $|b_2-b_2^0|$ on the RHS term (where summation also happens). Despite the bad conditioning the solution is still favorable.

Comment: But, even with this generation by cumulation, couldn't you normalize your lines afterwards ?

Comment: Yes I will try and let you know. Hope it won't ramp up the error on the RHS vector

Comment: I tried and got the following values:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|b_2-b_2^0\|_2}{\|b_2^0\|_2}=0.0091 (>0.0032).
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|x_2-x_2^0\|_2}{\|x_2^0\|_2}=0.0092 (>0.0075).
\end{equation}

The condition number is $cond(A_2)=171.48 (>155.4)$. This looks very strange, as the matrix does not "amplify" the error in the RHS term, but now has a larger condition number (which is a bit contradictory in my view).
I will try also line reduction and get back with a new comment.

Comment: No problem we can talk tomorrow sure and thank you! Got your email too.

Comment: I continued from the comment above and shared with you the plots via email. The idea is the condition number doesn't change, but the errors above stay very close together (which seems a bit contradictory to me). It's as if the matrix is unstable, but it is operated in a stable subspace.